# Powershell script worked and now doesn't. Compare-Object is used to then copy diff files to another folder

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm rather new to powersheell. I had used a script to compare to folders and then take the diff files and copy them to another folder:

```
$sfo = get-ChildItem "C:\Users\dempseym\Desktop\LON-G"

$sfoBu = get-ChildItem "C:\Users\dempseym\Desktop\G"

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\Users\dempseym\Desktop\NewDirG"

Compare-Object $sfo $sfoBu -Property Name |
    Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} |
    ForEach-Object {Copy-Item "C:\Users\dempseym\Desktop\LON-G\$($_.Name)" -Destination "C:\Users\dempseym\Desktop\NewDirG" -force }
```

I have foolishly spent two days looking at this and being unable to figure out why it doesn't work. And it did the other day.IF someone could take a look and let me know I would be so grateful.
Mark

Comment: your code shows "smart quotes" in your `New-Item` line. that often causes problems. try replacing the slanted/curly quotes with straight ones. ///// also, `robocopy` is often a better solution for this type of thing. it's faster, more robust, more consistent, and handles long file paths better. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you Lee_Daily and SimonS

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little ...  [*grin*]